# Double Icons of Favorite Applications in the Dock (Firefox Developer Edition) in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, .desktop, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I'm having an inconsistent user experience here. This is how I've added Firefox Developer Edition (FDE) to the dock:

1. Searched for FDE in the search dialog brought up with the super key.
2. Right-clicked the icon that came up (I made sure it wasn't some redundant `.desktop` file floating around on my disk but the actual application launcher).
3. Clicked on "Add to favorites".

Now, when I'm starting the application from the dock (or by searching it in the dash - it doesn't matter), instead of using the existing icon in the dock, another redundant icon appears in the dock, which does indicate open tabs (windows) but the existing icon doesn't and becomes useless.

So, when the application is running, I end up having the FDE icon twice, which looks like this.

[image: Double dock icon Firefox Developer Edition]

When doing the same thing for Chromium, only one icon appears in the dock and a red point left to it indicates open tabs (windows) as expected.

How do I debug this? Is this a known thing? Thanks for your help!